# Calculating a Future Position

Tags: java, math, position, latitude-longitude

I've got this information about an entity:

Lat/Long Position
Heading  (In Radians)
Speed (In  knots)

How do I calculate where the entities lat/long position will be at an arbitrary point in time (or figure out its position at intervals) assuming that the entity is moving in a straight line at a constant speed at a constant altitude?

(As you can tell, my math skills are weak)

Comment: This is off-topic (should be http://math.stackexchange.com or similar).

Comment: @Oli, this is fine for here. The math SE is really for higher-level math than this.

Comment: @Mike: Maybe you're right about Math SE.  But this question is completely independent of programming, so I disagree that it's on-topic here.

Comment: How do I move it to Math.stackexchange?

Comment: This would probably be quickly closed if migrated to math SE. Can you give us an example in code, even if it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

First, you cannot move on a straight line and at the same time at a constant altitude. Your Lat/Long coordinates are over a reference ellipsoid (most likely WGS84).
Their are various libraries or DB extensions that have a bunch of functions to do exactely these kinds of problems. Postgis for instance is one of them. Most of them are free and tested and do work. I would not recommend to try to implement this yourself (assuming the earth is a perfect sphere with radius r) as you must take into consideration the reference ellipsoid you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into consideration the answer provided by Hyperboreus, there is the aviation formulary here: http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm that has formulas for calculating a new lat/lon given a starting point, and angle, and a distance. You would have to calculate the distance yourself. It sounds like you have everything you need to calculate the distance though, as speed is just distance / time, and if you multiply that by the time offset you want to use, you've got your distance.

1 knot = 1 NM / hr
distance = yourTimeInDecimalHours * speed;

code sample to illustrate this (copied from the above referenced link):

```
double lat1 = 0, lon1 = 0;                      // NOTE: these are in radians - remember PI/2 radians = 90 degrees
double d = timeInDecimalHours * speedInKnots;   // so a half hour at 35 knots would be .5 * 35
double tc = usersTrueCourse;                    // aka user's heading
double lat=                                     // this will be in radians!!
    Math.asin(
        Math.sin(lat1) 
        * Math.cos(d)
        + Math.cos(lat1)
        * Math.sin(d)
        * Math.cos(tc)
    );
double lon = 0;
if (Math.cos(lat) == 0) {
    lon = lon1      // endpoint a pole
} else {
    lon = (lon1 - Math.asin(Math.sin(tc)*Math.sin(d)/Math.cos(lat)) + Math.PI % (2*Math.PI))-Math.PI;
}
```

Comment: Also, in reference to Hyperboreus' comment, I believe that the aviation formulary takes into account the fact that you can't move in a truly straight line and still maintain a constant altitude (with respect to the sphere of the earth). The cool thing about the aviation formulas is that they take this into account, and the calculations are all "great circle" math.

Comment: Althought its been quite some years after this, this happened to be the only reference I could find for the problem.
I have run your code, but the result does not seem to be correct. With a starting point of 50.912220795471718 / 11.938057949491478 which in radians is 0.88858588238330805 / 0.20835841751250919 and a distance of 0.666 and heading of 14.23 I will get a result of 0.61090132801892361 / -0.64214850458155048, which, converted back to deg equals 35.002068 / -36.792399.
Since the link above no longer exists, and I fail to find similar resources, could you maybe check the result?

Comment: Actually I was able to solve this. I came across https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/calculating-latitude-longitude-x-miles-from-point and then http://www.edwilliams.org/avform147.htm#Dist which helped tons. I had a mistake in the `mod(a, b)` part, and in addition the distance needs to be in radians. In your example, you need to add `double d = (M_PI/(180*60))*distanceNm;`. Of course this has to be done before calculating `lat` since it uses `d`.